# Stuck starting cups-browsed

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, printing, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on Dell XPS630i with no success. There's two problems:

1. bootloader does not install via ubuntu installer. Resolved this with the help of repair-boot. Mentioning this in case it has any effect on the next problem
2. After installation, Ubuntu hangs during boot on cup-browsed. HDD led just keeps blinking every second and that is it (tried leaving it like this for 30 minutes).

Here's the boot log (when I press ESC):

```
* Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon                                     [OK]
* Starting blueatooth daemon                                      [OK]
* Starting CUPS printing spooler/server                           [OK]
* Starting cups-browsed - Bonjour remote printer browsing daemon
```

I tried both 32 and 64 bit versions - same problem.

Computer specs - Dell XPS630i:

- Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 / 2.4 GHz
- XFX ATI HD 5770
- NVIDIA nForce 650i SLI chipset
- 4 x 2GB Kingston DDR2
- NVIDIA nForce raid controller with 2 x 320GB raid 0 and 1 x 500GB raid 0
- Auzentech Forte 7.1 audio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to work around it myself. Here are the steps

1. Boot to Live CD
2. Mount ubuntu partition and disable cups-browsed startup script

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/nvidia_abcdefg1 /mnt
   sudo chroot /mnt
   mv /etc/init/cups-browsed.conf /etc/init/cups-browsed.conf.disabled
   nano /etc/init/cups-browsed.conf.disabled   # comment out the code for `start on` then save the changes
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt
   exit
   ```
3. restart and boot as usual

This is not removing source of the problem, but at least I can now boot into OS.