# boot failure: Starting cups-browsed - bonjour remote printer browsing daemon

Tags: 14.04, boot, printing

i can't boot into my OS. Booting is stuck at 'Starting cups-browsed - bonjour remote printer browsing daemon'

Here the screenshoot : 
[image]

Why?

Comment: Is this issue solved? Just wanted to know because I'm facing this issue myself right now

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain how this works, but perhaps you'll find a solution here, which looks similar to this point, with the Bonjour Service:

[Stuck starting cups-browsed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323598/stuck-starting-cups-browsed)

BTW: +1 for the 'Screenshot'

Comment: i have tried. but it did not work.

Comment: Is this a dual boot computer? Do you have a GRUB menu, from where you can select which Operating system you'd like to start?